# Not Able Upload CSV data To database - (PANDAS)

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

i have a below script to upload csv data to database (PostgreSQL) but due to some issue  i was not able to upload data and getting an error. So ,How can i Fix this to upload data into database..

**import_data.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

# Define the PostgreSQL connection URL
DB_USERNAME = 'postgres'
DB_PASSWORD = '1234'
DB_HOST = 'localhost'
DB_PORT = '5432'
DB_NAME = 'store'

POSTGRES_URL = f'postgresql://{DB_USERNAME}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_HOST}:{DB_PORT}/{DB_NAME}'

engine = create_engine(POSTGRES_URL)

# Load the CSV files
store_timezones = pd.read_csv('bq-results-20230125-202210-1674678181880.csv', dtype={'store_id': 'int64'})
menu_hours = pd.read_csv('Menu_hours.csv', dtype={'store_id': 'int64', 'day': 'int8'})
store_status = pd.read_csv('store_status.csv', dtype={'store_id': 'int64'})

# Preprocess the 'timestamp_utc' column to remove 'UTC' part
store_status['timestamp_utc'] = store_status['timestamp_utc'].str.replace(' UTC', '')

# Parse datetime strings in 'store_status' and time strings in 'menu_hours'
store_status['timestamp_utc'] = pd.to_datetime(store_status['timestamp_utc'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', utc=True)
menu_hours['start_time_local'] = pd.to_datetime(menu_hours['start_time_local'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time
menu_hours['end_time_local'] = pd.to_datetime(menu_hours['end_time_local'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time

# Import data into the database
store_timezones.to_sql('store_timezones', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
menu_hours.to_sql('menu_hours', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
store_status.to_sql('store_status', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)

print('Data imported successfully')
```

**this is the error i'm facing**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rahul\Desktop\TEst submission\store-monitoring-api\scripts\import_raw_data.py", line 24, in <module>
    store_status['timestamp_utc'] = pd.to_datetime(store_status['timestamp_utc'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', utc=True)
  File "C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 1112, in to_datetime
    values = convert_listlike(arg._values, format)
  File "C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 488, in _convert_listlike_datetimes
    return _array_strptime_with_fallback(arg, name, utc, format, exact, errors)
  File "C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 519, in _array_strptime_with_fallback
    result, timezones = array_strptime(arg, fmt, exact=exact, errors=errors, utc=utc)
  File "strptime.pyx", line 534, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime
  File "strptime.pyx", line 355, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime
ValueError: time data "2023-01-25 05:01:37" doesn't match format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f", at position 1051895. You might want to try:
    - passing `format` if your strings have a consistent format;
    - passing `format='ISO8601'` if your strings are all ISO8601 but not necessarily in exactly the same format;
    - passing `format='mixed'`, and the format will be inferred for each element individually. You might want to use `dayfirst` alongside this.
```

Comment: Do you understand what the error message is telling you? The time you are trying to pass in is lacking the microseconds so it doesn't obey the expected format.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is due to the fact that you are trying to parse the `timestamp_utc` column with the format `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'`. This format expects a datetime string with microsecond precision, but the error message indicates that at least one of the values in the `timestamp_utc` column (specifically the value "2023-01-25 05:01:37" located at position 1051895) doesn't have this precision—it's missing the `.%f` part (microseconds).

You can remove the explicit format and let `pandas` infer the correct datetime format. This might be slightly slower if you have a lot of dates, but it's more flexible in cases like this.

You can Replace this line:

```py
store_status['timestamp_utc'] = pd.to_datetime(store_status['timestamp_utc'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', utc=True)
```

With this line:

```py
store_status['timestamp_utc'] = pd.to_datetime(store_status['timestamp_utc'], utc=True)
```